# silent print is not working [ Electron JS ]

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, electron

I tried to print the receipt using Electron JS the silent print is not working.
In github someone suggested me to downgrade to 3.1.11. I tried no use. It's still showing print dialog.

Print current page:

```
let win = BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow();
win.webContents.print({silent: true});
```

I tried to load the content in the different window also didn't worked

```
let win=new BrowserWindow({
    width:450,
    height:750,
    show: false
 });

win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/receipt.html?data=${data}`);

win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', () => {
 console.log("content loaded"  ;

 // Use default printing options
   win.webContents.print({ silent: true },(status)=>{
       console.log("print-status",status); 
   });    
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue before, that's how I fixed it:

1. Make sure your electron is downgraded globally by `Electron --version`
2. If the version number is not 3.1.11, that means your electron is still running under the old version. You need to re-install/downgrade it globally. I am using npm so the command line should look like `npm install electron@version --g`
3. Test if the code runs without silent mode `win.webContents.print({ silent: false})`

My issue was Electron wasn't downgraded globally (even the version number is correct in the package.json). I hope this helps you, I have spent days testing the Electron version for printing function. Hopefully, Electron 7 will be fully released at the end of this year.